# Unity3D build warning cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

Trying to build Android app but it triggered this warning. Though it was still built successfully.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.
```

```
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag>
```

This only happens in my M1 Macbook. It works completely fine when building the same project in Windows. Anyone has the same issue?

Unity 2018.4.23f1,
Android SDK Platform 30,
Available Android SDK Build-Tools: 32.0.0, 30.0.2, 28.0.3,
NDK 16.1.4479499,
Android Platform-Tools 33.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by reinstalling the Unity again. This warning is due to newer version of Android SDK manager makes changes to the old Android SDK folder and then the older SDK is not able to recognize the newer format.

Example case, I exported an Unity Android project and open it with Android Studio. Since I let the exported project to use the existing Android SDK (which is the Unity built in one), Android Studio (which has newer version of SDK manager) attempted to make changes to the Unity Android SDK. This causes the warning when building Android app in Unity subsequently.